# preg replace not working with file_get_content - removing brackets() & replacing words

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php 
$file = file_get_contents("http://www.mywebsite.net/folder/indexhtml.asp");
preg_match_all('~<td width="23%" height="23" align="right">(.*?)</td>~is',$file, $matches5);
print implode("\n", $matches5[0]);       //This prints out (Page: 889) on website ?>
```

I am trying to remove brackets and the word “Page” with “Number” from string called matches5 variable

Everytime I use this code below its shows blank which leaves me very confused. Please help me someone as im new to PHP
Second code

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents("http://www.mywebsite.net/folder/indexhtml.asp"); 
preg_match_all('~<td width="23%" height="23" align="right">(.*?)</td>~is',$file,  $matches5); 
$result = preg_replace('/(?<=^| ).(?=$| )/sm', '', $matches5); 
print implode("\n", $result[0]);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First example (bad):

```
$array = array("");
$replace = array("");
// Please put the maximum number this (Page: maximum)
for($i = 1; $i <= 1000; $i++)
{
array_push($array, "(Page: $i)");
// Put your replace string this or leave blank
array_push($replace, "I am replaced :)");
}

$file = 'I am (Page: 129) this is test.';

$new_string = str_replace($array, $replace, $file);

echo $new_string;
```

Second example (good).

```
$file = 'I am (Page: 129) this is test.';

$new_string = preg_replace('(Page: ([0-9]+))', "", $file);
$new_string = str_replace("()", "", $new_string);

echo $new_string;
```

Comment: output im getting is : Array

Comment: Problem is with your $file source, please try paste code to online test code http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and you will see, all work very well.